# How do I delete the Nth list item from a list of lists (column delete)?

Tags: python, list, slice, del

How do I delete a "column" from a list of lists?
Given:

```
L = [
     ["a","b","C","d"],
     [ 1,  2,  3,  4 ],
     ["w","x","y","z"]
    ]
```

I would like to delete "column" 2 to get:

```
L = [
     ["a","b","d"],
     [ 1,  2,  4 ],
     ["w","x","z"]
    ]
```

Is there a **slice** or **del** method that will do that? Something like:

```
del L[:][2]
```

Answer (score 14):

You could loop.

```
for x in L:
    del x[2]
```

If you're dealing with a lot of data, you can use a library that support sophisticated slicing like that.  However, a simple list of lists doesn't slice.

Comment: how do I save the resulting newlist into a new variable?

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K: This technique doesn't create new lists, it modifies the existing lists. However, you can copy the lists beforehand. `new_L = [list(row) for row in L]`... this is just one way to do things, it will create a shallow copy of each row, so when you modify `new_L` the original `L` will be unmodified.

Answer (score 7):

just iterate through that list and delete the index which you want to delete.

for example

```
for sublist in list:
    del sublist[index]
```

Comment: this solution is slow

Comment: Could you please then let me know what is the best ever solution for this Prob :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
>>> removed = [ l.pop(2) for l in L ]
>>> print L
[['a', 'b', 'd'], [1, 2, 4], ['w', 'x', 'z']]
>>> print removed
['d', 4, 'z']
```

It loops the list and pops every element in position 2.

You have got list of elements removed and the main list without these elements.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly twisted version:

```
index = 2  # Delete column 2 
[(x[0:index] + x[index+1:]) for x in L]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[(x[0], x[1], x[3]) for x in L]
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very easy way to remove whatever column you want.

```
L = [
["a","b","C","d"],
[ 1,  2,  3,  4 ],
["w","x","y","z"]
]
temp = [[x[0],x[1],x[3]] for x in L] #x[column that you do not want to remove]
print temp
O/P->[['a', 'b', 'd'], [1, 2, 4], ['w', 'x', 'z']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L = [['a', 'b', 'C', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4], ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']]
_ = [i.remove(i[2]) for i in L]
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that using a listcomp for its side effects is generally disfavoured, this won't work unless the element you're removing happens to be first in the list.  For example, if one of the sublists is [1,2,1,3], then the `remove` will return `[2,1,3]`, not `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind on creating new list then you can try the following:

```
filter_col = lambda lVals, iCol: [[x for i,x in enumerate(row) if i!=iCol] for row in lVals]

filter_out(L, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `pop()`:

```
[x.__delitem__(n) for x in L]
```

Here `n` is the index of the elements to be deleted.