# Remove the first items in a list of lists - make a copy instead of modifying in-place

Tags: python, list, slice, nested-lists

Let the array `a` be:

```
a = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

How can one obtain the following list?

```
b = [[2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: By creating a new list where each entry consists of one entry of the original list without the first element.

Comment: Related: [How do I delete the Nth list item from a list of lists (column delete)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13244466/7851470)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for this example, you could use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/7851470).

```
a = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
b = [x[1:] for x in a]
```